# Why are My Async Tasks Waiting for One Another to Finish?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, async-await

```
private async void StartTasks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    await Task.WhenAll(GetSomeData());
    lblResult.Text = "Got data?";
}

private async Task GetSomeData()
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 16;
    ServiceClient _proxy = new ServiceClient();

    //*** the wcf proxy service methods just sleep for 5 seconds.
    var t1 = _wcfProxy.A();
    var t2 = _wcfProxy.A();
    var t3 = _wcfProxy.A();
    var t4 = _wcfProxy.A();

    await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3,t4);
}
```

When I click my button, I'm expecting my label text to be set in `5 seconds` (since my WCF method calls are just sleeping for 5 seconds). Well, It's taking `10 seconds`. Now, when I only make three service calls, instead of four, the label gets set in `5 seconds`.

When I watch the Calls count in the performance monitor when I make all four calls, I only see 3 come in, then the other 1 comes in after the first three finish.

Comment: Are you testing against a WCF service instance run locally on the same machine? Also, what if you replace _wcfProxy.A/B calls with just Task.Delay(5000), does it work as expected then?

Comment: @Noseratio I know I'm answering this after you've already submitted an answer, but if it means anything...I am running it on a local machine, however the results are the same if I hit it from a different server. If I replace the ```Wcf``` calls, then it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this MSKB article: **[WCF service may scale up slowly under load](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2538826/wcf-service-may-scale-up-slowly-under-load).**

To sum up, it appears your WCF service's default IOCP thread pool is starving (it's hard to tell why; check with `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads` and `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads`). So most likely, when you block a WCF thread with `Thread.Sleep` while serving `_wcfProxy.A()`, there isn't another thread available to serve `_wcfProxy.B()`, so the `B` request gets queued until `A` has completed.

Try implementing `WorkerThreadPoolSynchronizer` and `WorkerThreadPoolBehaviorAttribute` as described in that article, apply `[WorkerThreadPoolBehavior]`to and `A` and `B` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: This is the reason, however I'm a little confused on how sending the Wcf call to a new thread from the Wpf application changes things. Threads from the Wpf app are related to the threads on the Wcf service?

Comment: Disregard my last comment. Sending it to a new thread doesn't fix the issue. However putting ```.ConfigureAwait(false)``` after your async wcf call fixes the issue, but that's not a separate question.

Comment: @James hmm sorry I wasn't clear, but I didn't even scratch the client (WPF) side of things, I was only talking about server side. Now I'm a bit confused myself, are you saying that adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` next to `await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2)` *in the client-side code* was making it work as expected?

Comment: I've made some changes to my code. After further investigating, I don't believe your answer is a solution. I've figured out that if I make 3 wcf calls, everything is fine, but as soon as I try to make 4 at the same time, this is when the wcf service doesn't get the 4th request until the first 3 are finished. I used the performance monitor and I see the 3 calls, then I see another call added on the chart after those finish.

Comment: Adding ```.ConfigureAwait(false)``` to the ```Task.WhenAll()``` does not fix the issue. When I add it to the individual service calls, it fixes the issue. Also, I checked my ```GetMinThreads``` on my Wcf, and the value is 6 worker threads. By logging to the console, unless I'm incorrect, I'm not using 6 threads for 4 requests.

Comment: @James How/where exactly do you add `ConfigureAwait` to individual calls? you can't just do var `t1 = _wcfProxy.A().ConfigureAwat()` because it doesn't return a task. Or, if you do `await _wcfProxy.A().ConfigureAwat()`, it's no longer a parallel task flow.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You're right. I had tested this a while back and thought that ```.ConfigureAwait()``` got me by it. I still think that Wpf is not sending the fourth request. I don't believe it's server side, though I could be wrong.

Comment: I believe you're correct on it being a ```Threading``` issue, however I've done a significant amount of debugging over the past 24 hours and I can't seem to figure out exactly where the cause is. I've moved the details to a new question that's more specific towards threading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796836/why-is-my-wcf-service-only-processing-3-parallel-requests-at-a-time