# Why is my WCF service only processing 3 parallel requests at a time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, threadpool, iis-8

I have a WPF application doing something very simple. I just have it firing off `4` requests to a basic `WCF Service`.

```
private async Task MultipleWcfCalls()
{
    ServiceReference.Service1Client _proxy = new ServiceReference.Service1Client();
    _proxy.Open();
    var t1 = _proxy.GetDataAsync(0);
    var t2 = _proxy.GetDataAsync(0);
    var t3 = _proxy.GetDataAsync(0);
    var t4 = _proxy.GetDataAsync(0);
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
}
```

My service is doing the classic `Task.Delay(3000)`.

```
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value)
{
    int other = 0;
    int workerThreadsAvail = 0;
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workerThreadsAvail, out other);
    await Task.Delay(3000);

    return workerThreadsAvail.ToString();
}
```

I expect `4` request to get fired off, and `3` seconds later, I want all four requests to return. Well, what's actually happening is all four requests are being sent over the wire, and the first three requests will return, then the last request will return `3` seconds after those.

**Throttling**

At first I thought this was my issue. Well, I added `<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10"/>` int my `web.config` and it didn't make any difference. So, then I read where it could be a connection limit that I'm reaching with my proxy, so I added `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit=10;` to my WPF application.

**Thread Starving**

Then, I kept coming across thread starving. So just as a test, I tried to set the minimum thread count to `20` to make sure that I had enough spun up to handle the `4` requests. I added this to my WPF application `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, 20);`. So to confirm that there were plenty of worker threads available to handle the requests, I decided to have my service call return the number of available threads at the beginning of the process. Every request returns `19` or `20`.

Using Fiddler, I can confirm that all `4` requests have been sent across the wire from the WPF (client) application. Now, my Wcf is using `basicHttpBinding`, so it's running in `Per Call` instance mode so concurrency mode shouldn't matter, but I've added `[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]` just to be safe.

I've done some stack tracing using the `System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener` and I can confirm that I get `3` requests logged at the same time (nearly), then the fourth request gets logged 3 seconds later.

The Wcf is hosted in `IIS`. If anymore information is needed, please let me know and I'll add it as soon as possible.

Per requested, here is my WCF interface.

```
namespace SampleWCF
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetData(int value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this have to do something with core in processor, quad = 4, 4-1 = 3 thread.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta I don't know too much about that stuff, but I believe I'm running on a Six-Core processor.

Comment: Is it the same if in your WCF code you do `await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false)`? Can you check if you have any synchronization context there (`SynchronizationContext.Current?.GetType()?.Name`)?

Comment: @Noseratio Adding ```.ConfigureAwait(false)``` doesn't make any difference (though I'm not sure what that actually does). Also, ```SynchronizationContext.Current``` is null.

Comment: About thread starving: the beauty of async/await is that both your server and client should be able to run this on 1 thread each.

Comment: So forget about threads, there must be another throttling option you overlooked. WCF just has way too many of them.

Comment: For diagnostics, get the Thread.Current.ManagedThreadId before and aftere the await and return those in your string.

Comment: @James interesting... is there any behavior difference in Release vs Debug builds? Have you tried the `[WorkerThreadPoolBehavior]` I linked in the other post?

Comment: Also I wonder if you get the expected behavior outside IIS, e.g., using [WCF self-hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application).

Comment: @HenkHolterman 1. So when we use the ```async/await``` pattern in both WCF and WPF, does that automatically handle sending things to worker threads? 2. When I return the beginning and end ```CurrentThreadId```, I get results as follows (before the wait:after the await) ```22:18```, ```17:21```, ```22:13```, ```17:20```.

Comment: @Noseratio 1. There is no difference in ```release``` or ```debug``` mode. 2. I haven't tried the ```[WorkerThreadPoolBehavior]```. 3. I self-hosted it and it worked as expected. All ```4``` calls got send and returned at the same time.

Comment: async != threading. On WPF, you don't need extra threads and you should avoid them. On WCF, you wouldn't see much difference with < 20 calls. AspNetCore is optimized for async, WCF is not.

Comment: I would call this no repro - WCF normally shouldn't do this, so probably a WCF or IIS setting. And I'm weary of that GetDataAsync name - does the client also have a generated GetDataAsyncAsync ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No. The client generated ```GetDataAsync```.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just changed the name in the WCF service to ```GetData()```. Makes no difference.

Comment: Hmmm, then what does your interface looks like? And do post _exact_ code, copy-pasted.  WCF has its own async naming conventions.

Comment: Also note that the async in WCF and WPF are totally independent - you can call an async method synchronous and vice versa. So ignore the WPF part, this is all about WCF.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just added the interface.

Comment: @James, from your answers to the comments it's clear this is specific to your IIS config. Hard to take it any further without being able to repro. I suggest you try `WorkerThreadPoolBehavior` and also make sure the services runs in its own IIS app pool. Here's another useful MSKB article for further troubleshooting: [Contention, poor performance, and deadlocks when you make calls to Web services from an ASP.NET application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821268/contention-poor-performance-and-deadlocks-when-you-make-calls-to-web-s). Please post your own answer if you track it down.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, [this](https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit) is the only thing that I have found that may explain this behavior. I'm running `IIS 8` on `Windows 10`. Though I can't find the limit for my exact version combination, I think this could potentially be the issue.

It seems that Microsoft would put a limit on the number of simultaneous requests. For some of the basic versions, 3 would be the limit. I can't seem to alter these settings anywhere, so if you know how, please post another answer for someone else who comes across this.

Comment: Interesting indeed, and it has surfaced before without a proper workaround (besides some suggesting using IIS Express): https://stackoverflow.com/q/33024015/1768303